# Apache2: File Access (Mod Ruby)

Tags: ruby, apache2, file-access

I have a VirtualHost in my Apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 127.0.0.1
   ServerAlias localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/rocketruby/public
   <Directory /var/www/rocketruby/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redharbor.rbx
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`redharbor.rbx` is in `/var/www/rocketruby/public` and it's access-mode is 0777.

Sadly I get this message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /redharbor.rbx on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

What has gone wrong, please help!

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas to try...

Try adding two lines as shown below, for "Order" and "Allow", then reload Apache and try accessing your script:

```
<Directory /var/www/rocketruby/public>
  AllowOverride all
  Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redharbor.rbx
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Are the public directories open? You want to see an "x" for the last access letter:

```
$ ls -ld /var/www/rocketruby/public
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 4096 ...
```

If you delete the rewrite, then reload Apache, does the script work?

```
$ wget http://localhost/redharbor.rbx
(or use a web browser)
```

If you delete the rewrite, then reload Apache, can you access a static page?

```
$ cd /var/www/rocketruby/public
$ echo "Hello" > index.html
$ wget http://localhost/index.html
(or use a web browser)
```

Are you able to run the script from your command line, i.e. not via Apache?

```
$ ruby /var/www/rocketruby/public/redharbor.rbx
```

Have you turned on Ruby in your Apache conf?

```
<IfModule mod_ruby.c>
  RubyRequire apache/ruby-debug
  # Execute *.rbx files as Ruby scripts
  <Files *.rbx>
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler ruby-object
    RubyHandler Apache::RubyDebug.instance
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```

If you still need help, see if you can take a look at the Apache error logs and post the results here.

Comment: can you clarify? are you saying that you tried everything I posted, but none of it worked? In other words, your Apache can't load the index.html file? This would simplify the problem because that means it's about Apache and your filesystem, not about Ruby nor RBX.